# How to construct a table using data from different files?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two different files. One called `movie`, which contains the name of several movies and the year they were realized, and the other called `time` which contains the name of several movies, the year they were realized and their running time.

I want to create a table using MySQL with all the movies from the file `movie`, with their running time from the file `time`. But I only want the movies listed in the file `movie`, and it appears that several movies appear in the file `time`, but not in the file `movie`.

Do you have any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load every file into a table with the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command.

Then create a third table and insert into it whatever you need. Here's a good explanation about [joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

You will want to do a `LEFT JOIN` :)